# neo4j get parent of a node of a given id

Tags: neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I have this Neo4J database and I have the id of the nodes of interest. I need to find the parent of those nodes. 
How can I do this? 
I am using py2neo and I have a neo4j object.

Problem is I don't know Cypher at all and not even Gremlin.
What cypher query will give me the result?

Comment: Please provide more context and describe what have you tried so far? If you use internal identifiers, a query like `MATCH (n) WHERE id(n) = ... RETURN n` will give you the node for a particular id. Then you can go on to grab the parent, but your question did not state how "parent" is defined in your graph.

Comment: @GaborSzarnyas I graph created joern fuzzy parser and the nodes with id. Nodes are functions for different files and parents are the files. I don't know the relation really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are not sharing your data model I'm assuming you have nodes with `:PARENT_OF` relationship between them. Something like `(:Node)-[:PARENT_OF]->(:Node)`.

If you have the internal id of the node of interest, you should use the [id() function](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/scalar/#functions-id):

```
MATCH (nodeOfInterest:Node)<-[:PARENT_OF]-(parent:Parent)
WHERE id(nodeOfInterest) = 10
RETURN parent
```

If the id you have is a property, then you can directly use it in the pattern matching:

```
MATCH (nodeOfInterest:Node {id : 10})<-[:PARENT_OF]-(parent:Parent)
RETURN parent
```

I suggest you to take a look in these links:

- [Neo4j Developer Manual - Introduction](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/introduction/)
- [Neo4j free e-books](https://neo4j.com/books/)
- [Neo4j Free Online Training](https://neo4j.com/graphacademy/online-training/)

Comment: It's not that I don't want to but I don't know. Thank you I will get back to this once I get more information.